# Get Metadata of BLOB Storage with no directory in ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory

Rather than creating a dataset per directory, I created just one so I can use a parameter to change the directory:
[image]

That will enable me to get the metadata of a particular directory within a particular contaier:
[image]

Problem though is I seem to have to put something in that Directory parameter, but a file can sit in the container level but not in directory, so when I try to set the parameter as a blank I get this error:
`The required Blob is missing. Folder path: ebayordersuat/""/.`

Is there anyway round this apart from creating a dummy folder and put everything in there so the directory starts with the dummy folder?

Answer (score 0):

worked it out, just need to put a space into the parameter and that's it!